# how can I compile c++ on my operating system

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, operating-system, homebrew

I'm developing an operating system in intel x86-64 assembly and I would like it to be able to compile c++. Is there a way to create a compiler for my operating system without starting from scratch?

Comment: It's a bit chicken-and-egg. How can you create a compiler for your operating system if you don't have the operating system on which to create teh compiler...!

Comment: There's a useful post here you may wish to start reading [how create a c compiler without a c native-compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698786/how-create-a-c-compiler-without-a-c-native-compiler)

Comment: It should be possible to port g++.